# scrapay+xpath retornando array vazio

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, xpath

Estou aprendendo a criar um crawler com scrapy + xpath.
Porem, quando eu dou o comando
`scrapy shell https://br.udacity.com/courses/all/`
O sitema retorna isso como se tudo estivesse normal:

`2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: courses) 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) - [GCC 9.3.0], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020), cryptography 3.3.1, Platform Linux-5.4.0-64-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'courses', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'courses.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['courses.spiders']} 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: a0c1cc56ede9b7e3 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions: ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats', 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole', 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage'] 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2021-01-22 15:40:58 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.udacity.com/robots.txt> from <GET https://br.udacity.com/robots.txt> 2021-01-22 15:40:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.udacity.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) 2021-01-22 15:40:59 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.udacity.com/courses/all/> from <GET https://br.udacity.com/courses/all/> 2021-01-22 15:40:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.udacity.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) 2021-01-22 15:40:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.udacity.com/courses/all/> (referer: None) [s] Available Scrapy objects: [s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc) [s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f5d451e7070> [s]   item       {} [s]   request    <GET https://br.udacity.com/courses/all/> [s]   response   <200 https://www.udacity.com/courses/all/> [s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f5d45263d30> [s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7f5d445485e0> [s] Useful shortcuts: [s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed) [s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects  [s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help) [s]   view(response)    View response in a browser` 
Então eu aplico o response para ver se eu estou dentro do site ainda ele responde normal segue trecho:

```
    >>> response
    <200 https://www.udacity.com/courses/all/>
```

entao eu aplico :

`>>> div = response.xpath('//*[@id="ud860"]')`

E ao  dar comando Div para retornar o html da div ele retorna um array vazio, vou colocar um print para visualizar melhor.

[image: print da imagem com os retornos]

Como posso resolver isso?Pelo que li era pra retornar o html  com os dados da div, mas não sei  se eu não estou usando direito a ferramenta ou esta faltando modulos no meu python! :´(

Comment: a primeira coisa que você precisa se certificar é que seu xpath está buscando de fato algum elemento, eu particularmente abri o site que você mencionou, pesquisei lá pelo xpath e ele não existia

Comment: Então @LucasMiranda  alterei para outro xpath e ainda retorna a mesma coisa. 
vou colocar o codigo aqui : 
'>>> response
<200 https://www.udacity.com/courses/all/>
>>> div = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/article/div[3]')
>>> div
[]
>>> 
'
uma parada que notei que o terminal de geral aparece o input e output com as linha e o meu não. sera que ta com erro meus pacotes  Ou é só neura minha?

Comment: mas você testou esse xpath e viu que ele realmente retorna a div que você deseja? eu abri aqui novamente passando esse xpath ai e novamente não encontrei nada, se você quiser pegar as divs com os cursos voce devia tentar por exemplo //*[@class='catalog-component__card']

Comment: @LucasMiranda Com o xpath que você me enviou  apareceu o conteúdo dentro do array, eu devo estar copiando o xpath de forma errada.
Eu entro no  site inspeciono o elemento e pego a primeira classe e dou um copy xpath, é assim mesmo?

Comment: a forma que você fez é pra funcionar, sinceramente não sei o porque o seu está gerando isso ai (pra mim gerou algo bem diferente fazendo o mesmo processo), o ideal é que você entenda o funcionamento do xpath para poder otimizar a busca do seu elemento e não dependa dessa geração automática